# Is "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" guarantee to be the alias for "rowid"?

Tags: sqlite

I have read https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html but still not fully confirm the following idea.

I was wondering, `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL` guarantee to be the alias for `rowid`?

For instance, for the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `attachment` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `name` TEXT NOT NULL, ... )
```

Will

```
select * from attachment order by id;
```

equivalent to

```
select * from attachment order by rowid;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The link you are refering to describe the various algorithm used to select a default rowid (with ou without `AUTOINCREMENT`).

The rules for a primary key to be an *integer primary key* (and so an alias for the rowid) are detailed in [ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) :

- The type must be exactly `INTEGER` (case insensitive)
- The declaration of the column must not include `PRIMARY KEY DESC`

SQLite goes to great lengths to keep the documented behaviours (and sometime undocumented, e.g. the second rule is there not to break the compatibility with an old bugged version)

So `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL` is an alias for the rowid *and* select the algorithm that guaranties that generated rowids will never be reused, even if you delete rows.